# Is it OK to install an irrigation system in a half longitudinal sectioned drain pipe, under the slabs of a garden edge?

Tags: irrigation

Here is the picture that is worth 1000 words
Since I am about to install the edging that you see in the backyard (area covered by the runs 1-4) I am considering installing the irrigation runs in a channel formed by cutting a drain pipe in half along the longitudinal axis and then install the slabs that make the edge on top. The actual shape of the path will be pure rectangular I gave up on the zig-zags you see in the picture
Do you see any issues raised by this design? The idea is to be able to reach the pipes easily without digging them out of the ground. This will add support to the slabs as well

[image]

Comment: Is it likely to freeze still water in the pipes ?  And is the drain pipe likely to clog with leaves etc ?

Comment: I can fillit up with pea gravel , it will be perfororated drain,will not be open for leaves to get in, the slabs will cover it all

Comment: what is the light gray area made of? ... the only problem that you could face is if the light gray area and the 1/2 drain pipe settle at different rates ... you could skip the use of the 1/2 pipe and use sand instead ... it would be easy to dig up if needed

Comment: Yeah you have a good point. The slabs on top are stone   or concrete, I have not decided that yet. I could fill up the half drain pipe with pea gravel or sand.  The idea is that if I want to remove everything later I wont have to remove dirt and sans mixed and all that